# Thymeleaf reference using element id

Tags: java, templates, thymeleaf

I have a button like this in my template

```
<button id="start-button" th:text="#{start-button}">no thymeleaf</button>
```

I am trying to remove the duplication in the `th` reference ("start-button" in my example) so the text always comes from a property with the same id as the element

Is there any way to tell thymeleaf to take the property name `#{start-button}` from the `id` tag? Ideally, I want to have the id hardcoded by me and the `th:text` reference it, not the other way around. All I was able to find in my search is ways to create the id dynamically in thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.  The closest you can get is using the same variable to generate both the id and the text.  Something like this:

```
<button th:with="button='start-button'" th:id="${button}" th:text="#{${button}}" />
```